Does borrowing from 401K count as personal debt?
I am trying to put together some downpayment for a house purchase. My 401K provider allows borrowing from it before retirement, as long as it is used towards purchasing primary residence.
My question is: does this count as personal debt when it comes to mortgagee application? Since I am just borrowing from my own money, I don't know if it is going to be reported on a credit enquiry. If it does not get reported, the bank does not see it, and thus does not take that into consideration when it calculates the debt to income ratio?

"not showing on credit report" != "Not debt". You're required to disclose your debts to the bank, if only what's reported counted they wouldn't be asking you to fill the form.

Are you sure the application doesn't ask where your down payment is coming from?

This is an unwise choice despite some changes to the tax law.  If anything, lower your contribution rate and just save the money.  You are better off paying PMI than borrowing from your 401K.
